# Amount of words to speak during one's lifetime

Tags: sources-mekorot, words

I read somewhere that, *"Every person is granted a certain amount of words to speak during his lifetime, except for that which pertains to Torah and mitzvos. Thus, every person can add some years to his life by carefully choosing went to speak."*

Does anyone know where the source for this can be found?

Answer (score 4):

[Derech Pikudecha (Bnei Yisoschor)- page 162 - paragraph starting with Gimel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4702&st=&pgnum=161) says that one has a limit on the amount of words in his lifetime and if he speaks too much is shortening his life.

> קיבלנו מרבותינו בפסוק: 'נפשי יצאה בדברו', שיש שיעור לאדם כמה ידבר כל
>   ימי חייו, ואם ירבה לדבר שלא במקום מצווה, הנה ממעט החיות

[Sefer Darkei Tzedek - page 10 - #54](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24592&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=) also mentions this concept.

> לא ירבה דיבורים שלא לצורך, כי הדיבורים בזמן חיי האדם קצובים מן השמים
>   ולמה לו לקצר חייו בדיבורים שאינן של מצווה, ואין צריכים לו כלל, כמאמר
>   שלמה המלך עליו השלום בשיר השירים: ונפשי יצאה בדברו. נפשי שנתתי באדם
>   יוצא בדברו

Thanks to [Rabbi Shlomo Aviner](http://www.havabooks.co.il/article_ID.asp?id=364) for this answer.